# Target class [OrderController] does not exist. after renaming Controller and model

Tags: php, laravel, routes, php-8.2

When I started the project in Laravel I had a ReturnController. But because of naming conventions I had to rename it to OrderController. I renamed Controller and Model, I run all the `php artisan cache:clear, php artisan route:cache, php artisan config:cache ...` etc but when I try to create an order in the `views\orders\add.blade.php` (the form's action is `action="{{ route('orders.store') }}"`)

I get the error `Target class [OrderController] does not exist.`

Here is the `web.php` contents:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');

Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', [App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'showOrders'])->name('orders');

Route::get('/orders/create', [App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'create'])->name('orders.create');

Route::get('/orders', [App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class, 'index']);
```

What am I missing? How I can fix this before I rewrite the whole application from scratch with the correct controller name?

Another clue is that in order to navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/home` strangely I had to add the line `use App\Models\Order` in the OrderController.php in order to work... so here is the OrderController.php in order it helps...

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\Models\Order;
use App\Models\Customer;
use App\Models\Product;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $customers = Customer::all();
        $products = Product::all();
        return view('orders.add', compact('customers', 'products'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(string $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(string $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(Request $request, string $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(string $id)
    {
        //
    }

    public function showOrders()
    {
        $orders = Order::with(['customer', 'products'])->get();

        return view('home', compact('orders'));
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, no need to mention the full path of controller.
Second, have you renamed the controller file also ? Or you just changed the class name in the file ?

Answer (score 0):

In web.php, instead of:

```
Route::resource('customers', 'CustomerController');

Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
```

Use:

```
Route::resource('customers', App\Http\Controllers\CustomerController::class);
Route::resource('orders', App\Http\Controllers\OrderController::class);
```

Comment: tried but still the same....